# GPIO pins of CC2650 are capable of driving the opto-coupler(4n35) directly?

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator

I need to drive opto-coupler(4n35) from the GPIO pins of the CC2650 (Pins other than high drive capability).

Are the GPIO pins of CC2650 capable of driving the optocoupler  directly? Will they supply sufficient current required by the optocoupler?

Comment: Most likley not. You can see the output as a avoltage source (although weak) and your optocoupler needs a current source. A resistor of suitable values in between should solve your problems.

Comment: optocoupler like 4n35 require-IF=10mA and Vf=1.5V that means a 3.3V PWM input at 4n35 requires 180 ohm in series. Am i Right?
Can CC2650 supply 10mA on the GPIO pins?                                     
I am trying to amplify 3.3V PWM output from CC2650 to 10V PWM signal using opto-coupler and transistor..

Comment: Good. Then you have all data needed to calculate the resistor required.

Comment: What is the maximum current i can draw from GPIO of CC2650?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: ~200uA with pullup resistor

Comment: Then you need to buffer somehow with external circutry.

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Pretty much anyone of these: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-buffers-drivers-receivers-transceivers/704?k=buffer&k=&pkeyword=buffer&pv276=1109&pv276=1668&pv276=985&pv276=893&pv276=759&pv276=1292&pv276=760&pv276=2806&pv276=360&pv276=384&pv276=2915&pv276=983&pv276=1124&pv276=16&pv276=743&pv276=114&pv276=34&pv276=1495&pv276=197&pv276=1390&pv276=20&pv276=1197&pv276=2919&pv276=25&pv276=141&pv276=19&pv276=79&FV=ffe002c0%2Ca4006d%2Ca40010%2Ca40134%2Ca40372%2Ca4039b%2C1f140000&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4N35 is designed for a current of 10 mA.
It is possible to use a smaller current, but then there is no guarantee for the current transfer ratio, so you'd have to use the datasheet's typical values and apply a large safety factor.
For example, for I<sub>F</sub> = 5 mA, the datasheet claims that a collector current of about 6 mA might be possible, but to account for manufacturing variations and temperature effects, better make the output resistor large enough so that the collector current is no more than about 1 mA:

[image: 4N35 IC vs. VCE]

The CC2650 is capable of driving 4 mA on all GPIOs, or 8 mA on high-drive GPIOs. (The V<sub>OL</sub>/V<sub>OH</sub> specifications in the datasheet show how large the internal voltage drop can be at these currents.)
The "GPIO pullup current" specification describes the built-in pullup resistors.

If possible, replace the 4N35 with a better optocoupler: the PC817 (or any of its many "xx817" clones) is specified for 5 mA, and the H11L1 would work at 1.6 mA.

Comment: Hi...If i am using H11L1 what should be the value of current limiting resistor between CC2650 gpio and opto isolator ?

Comment: Size the resistor so that you get about 2 mA. The H11L1's LED has a forward voltage of about 1.1 V (see the datasheet), so (3.3 V − 1.1 V) / 2 mA ≈ 1 kΩ.